# Relationship between 'Exit Pupil' and 'Pupil Plane'

Tags: optics, fourier-transform

I am having trouble to understand the relationship between the 'Pupil Plane' from the Fourier Optics Theory and the 'Exit Pupil' from Geometrical Optics. It seems that both are different concepts, but are somehow connected to each other.

**My understanding:**

*Exit Pupil:* Image of Aperture Stop (seen from image side)

*Pupil Plane:* Is positioned at the aperture of the optical system. The 'pupil function' is given by the aperture stop shape at this position. The Fourier transform of this 'pupil function' gives the coherent impulse response of the system.

**What I've read and don't understand completely**

According to [1](https://doi.org/10.1364/OE.21.015131):

> In an aberration-free coherent imaging system, the *light field distribution at the pupil plane (i.e., the back focal plane of the objective lens)* is directly proportional to the Fourier transform of the light field at the object plane. Therefore, the spatial coordinates at the object plane and the pupil plane can be expressed as (x, y) and (kx, ky), respectively, with kx and ky as the wave number in the x and y directions. Due to such a Fourier relationship, aberrations of an imaging platform are often characterized at the pupil plane for simplicity [Goodman - Introduction to Fourier Optics].

However, I dont understand why the back focal plane of an optical system should necessarily be a pupil plane. Furthermore, I cannot find the exact quote in [Goodman - Introduction to Fourier Optics].

Acoording to [2](http://kmdouglass.github.io/posts/simple-pupil-function-calculations/):

> The pupil function and the pupil planes of a system are not the same thing. The entrance and exit pupils--which together are known as the pupil planes--are the planes in which the images of the system's aperture stop are located. The pupil function, however, is not an image of the aperture stop of the system; it's a 2D Fourier transform of a field.
> There is never-the-less a relationship between the pupil function and the plane of the exit pupil. The pupil function represents the relative amplitude and phase of the field on the surface of a so-called reference sphere that intersects the optics axis in the plane of the system's exit pupil.

However, I can't find another source that confirms this statement and I am not sure if this is really correct.

**Questions**

*Question 1:* Is my understanding of the defintion of the words 'Exit Pupil' and 'Pupil Plane' correct?

*Question 2:* What is the relationship between the 'exit pupil' and the 'pupil plane'? Are they at the same position in an optical system? Is there a mathematical expression that states the light field relationship between both planes?

Answer (score 1):

Coming at it first from the geometrical side: in any optical system there are several optical spaces separated by focussing surfaces. The first space has the object at one end and the entrance pupil at the other. In each space there are images of these two planes, called image planes and pupil planes (possibly virtual). At the output end we have the exit pupil and the final image. One of the actual pupil planes contains the aperture which limits the ray bundle; this is often but does not have to be the entrance pupil plane. It also is often hard edged, but does not have to be, it may be graded to be a smooth function. So pupil planes are just images, either upstream or downtream, of the actual physical aperture.

The key word in quotation 1 is 'aberration free'. This means that all pupil planes are equivalent geometrically. This is usually rather idealised! The relationship of the light field between image planes (all of them) and pupil planes (all of them) is then a Fourier Transform one. Since a sharp-edged function has an infinite Fourier transform, the distributions in the internal planes may get truncated, leading to further complications.

Comment: Hello CWPP, thanks for your fast answer! However, I do not understand why the pupil planes and image planes are generally (without aberrations) related by a Fourier Transform. Is there a mathematical/physical/optical derivation for this?